# Main activity screen with buttons showing later after app is run in emulator

Tags: android

I am a new comer to Android app.When I run an app with buttons in it in the emulator, the buttons are shown after the app is completed, so onclick etc is not working.

It shows a blank white screen

This same code is from a youtube video and there it is working fine. Tried to debug but couldnt make much headway.

Pasting the code :

```
package com.example.weatherapiapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_cityID,btn_getWeatherByID,btn_getWeatherByName;
    EditText et_dataInput;
    ListView lv_weatherReport;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       //assign values  to each control on the layout
       btn_cityID = findViewById(R.id.btn_getCityID);
       btn_getWeatherByID = findViewById(R.id.btn_getWeatherByCityID);
       btn_getWeatherByName = findViewById(R.id.btn_getWeatherByCityName);

       et_dataInput = findViewById(R.id.et_dataInput);
       lv_weatherReport = findViewById(R.id.lv_weatherReports);

       //click listeners for each button

       btn_cityID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You clicked me 1.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           }
       });

       btn_getWeatherByID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You clicked me 2.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           }
       });

       btn_getWeatherByName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You clicked me 3.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           }
       });

    }
}
```

The activity_main.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_getCityID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get City ID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_getWeatherByCityID"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_getWeatherByCityID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Weather by ID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_getWeatherByCityName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_getCityID"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btn_getCityID" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_getWeatherByCityName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Weather by Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_getWeatherByCityID"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btn_getWeatherByCityID" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_dataInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="City Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_getCityID" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_weatherReports"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="628dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_dataInput" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can you help in letting me know what may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot `.show()` in toast

it should be

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You clicked me 1.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the silly issue.It worked fine.

Comment: if you find my answer usefull ...then accept my answer